# Работа программы

Tags: c++

Что должен вывести данный код? Как ни странно, он компилируется.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << '/dd1s';
}
```

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо ещё.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

`'/dd1s'` - это ["многосимвольный (multichar) литерал"](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#2), типом которого является `int`.

В зависимости от реализации компилятора '/dd1s' преобразуется в `int` (например через переполнение), и этот `int` выводится в stdout.

Comment: а в 8ричную систему не перевоодит?

Comment: в 16ричную точнее